# Declaring a dictionary in function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I was writing a code

```
import Data.Map

main = print $ scores ["APPLE","bbd","cat"]
score :: String -> Int
score = sum . map latterScore

scores :: [String] -> [Int]
scores arrayOfStrings = [ score word | word <- arrayOfStrings]

myLookup :: Char -> Int
myLookup inputChar = x <- Data.Map.fromList([("A",1), ("B",3), ("C", 3), ("E", 1), ("D", 2), ("G", 2), ("F", 4), ("I", 1), ("H", 4), ("K", 5), ("J", 8), ("M", 3), ("L", 1), ("O", 1), ("N", 1), ("Q", 10), ("P", 3), ("S", 1), ("R", 1), ("U", 1), ("T", 1), ("W", 4), ("V", 4), ("Y", 4), ("X", 8), ("Z", 10)])
        case Data.Map.lookup inputChar x of Nothing -> undefined
                                        (Just v) -> v
```

But that is showing a error as  parse error on input '<-' in  line 1 i.e., the dictionary
and can we write this code without using the case?

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but you can replace `scores arrayOfStrings = [ score word | word <- arrayOfStrings ]` with `scores = map score`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<-` is used in list comprehensions and `do` notation, and you're using neither. You probably  meant to use `let`:

```
myLookup inputChar = let x = ... in case Data.Map.lookup inputChar x of ...
```

Other options would be using `where`:

```
myLookup inputChar = case Data.Map.lookup inputChar x of ...
  where x = ...
```

Or just introducing a module-level binding:

```
x = ...

myLookup inputChar = case Data.Map.lookup inputChar x of ...
```

As for removing the `case`, you can use [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromJust) after importing `Data.Maybe`:

```
fromJust $ Data.Map.lookup inputChar x
```

Heck, you could even embed the `fromList` right in there:

```
fromJust $ Data.Map.lookup inputChar $ Data.Map.fromList ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the case expression, you can use `maybe` defined in `Data.Maybe` which has the following type:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

By analyzing the type signature, you can guess what it does. Notice that type `b` is the type of the final output.

1. The first argument is the "default" value returned when we pass `Nothing` as input.
2. The second argument is a function applied to `x` when the input is `Just x`.
3. The third argument is the input itself.

Let's give it a try!

```
> import Data.Maybe
> maybe 7 (+1) Nothing
7
> maybe 7 (+1) (Just 1)
2
```

This is much safer than using `fromJust` which will break when you pass `Nothing` to it.

```
> fromJust Nothing
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

Your case expression can be written as:

```
maybe 0 id (Data.Map.lookup inputChar x)
```

Notice the use of `0` instead of `undefined`. Zero is the neutral element of addition, which won't change the result of the sum. This way you have a function which is completely safe and cannot fail for any input.

As suggested in the comments, when the function you are passing to `maybe` is `id` it is better to use `fromMaybe` instead.

```
-- fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe 0 (Data.Map.lookup inputChar x)
```

Here is the complete version (I modified it a little):

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe

main = print $ map score ["APPLE", "bbd", "cat"]

score :: String -> Int
score = sum . map myLookup

myLookup :: Char -> Int
myLookup inputChar = fromMaybe 0 (M.lookup inputChar dict)
  where dict = M.fromList [('A',1),('B',3),('C',3),('E',1),('D',2),('G',2)
                          ,('F',4),('I',1),('H',4),('K',5),('J',8),('M',3)
                          ,('L',1),('O',1),('N',1),('Q',10),('P',3),('S',1)
                          ,('R',1),('U',1),('T',1),('W',4),('V',4),('Y',4)
                          ,('X',8),('Z',10)
                          ]
```

Comment: If you run [HLint](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/) on `maybe 0 id`, it will suggest using [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) instead.